# Header('Location') equivalent in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, redirect

I need to refresh the current page with new get variables. I've read that you need to inject $route and use the reload method, but this only reloads the current url.

I would like to essentially do something akin to PHP:

```
header('Location:currenturl?get1=value1&get2=value2')
```

In AngularJS, NOT send an http.get request, but force the browser to load a new URL in the same window (in this case the modified get url). How can I do this in AngularJS? Does reload accept a parameter for a custom URL?

*I've just began to learn AngularJS and JS a few days ago, sorry if this is an obvious question, but I can't seem to find an answer that doesn't open a new tab

Comment: so what you want is change your currentUrl from `currenturl?get1=value1&get2=value2` to `currenturl?get1=value3&get2=value4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$window.location.href

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Answer (score 0):

Why no plain old [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location)?

Comment: A better practice would be to us the angular-provided, injectable $window object.

Comment: Interesting, never saw that object!